# Drag item and drop it inside other element

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to drag an item from List1 and drop it inside another element (`<div>`, `<ul>`, etc...).
the picture below will explain the example : 
[image]

Like you can see I need to drop the first element inside one of the list in top, when it's dropped the number of stops will increase by one and the dragged element will disappear 
I am using Angular 7 with cdk, but I didn't figure out how to do it

Here is my current code
HTML:

```
  <perfect-scrollbar>
        <div class=" table-full-width table-hover">
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table">
              <tbody #StaffTable>
              <tr class="" (click)="SelectedStaff($event)" *ngFor="let staff of staffs"  style="background-color: #f9f9f9">
                <td class="row" [id]="staff.id">
                  <div class="col-md-3">
                    <i class="material-icons">local_shipping</i>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-7">
                    {{staff.name}}<br>
                    Stops: {{staff.nbsc}}<br>

                  </div>
                </td>

              </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </perfect-scrollbar>
     <div style="position: fixed;bottom: 0px;width: 14%">
       <perfect-scrollbar>
         <div class=" table-full-width table-hover"   *ngIf="serviceCaseNoStaff">
           <div class="table-responsive">
             <table class="table">
               <tbody cdkDropList
                      (dropped)="drop($event)"

               >
               <tr cdkDrag  *ngFor="let servicecase of serviceCaseNoStaff"  style="background-color: #f9f9f9">
                 <td class="row" [id]="servicecase.id">
                   <div class="col-md-3">
                     <i class="material-icons">local_shipping</i>
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-md-9">
                     {{servicecase.company.name}} <br>
                     {{servicecase.address.postcode}} {{servicecase.address.city}}

                   </div>
                 </td>

               </tr>
               </tbody>
             </table>
           </div>
         </div>
       </perfect-scrollbar>
     </div>
```

TS:

```
drop(event) {
console.log(event);
```

}

Thanks.

Comment: You can use ngDragula library that does this for you.

Comment: I tried to follow but nothing, I mean when the dragged object is near the dropped object, this one need to change color for example and when I drop it it go inside the box and no more visible